# GWT uploading a file to a unix path

Tags: gwt, file-upload

I'm kinda puzzled how does a unix path looks like. I have followed an example to write a simple fileuploader using GWT. But the guide was written with Windows in mind. Say if I have C drive. In windows I would told the program to save the files to C:\save_here\

But in unix, I'm using ubuntu, there are no C drives or other drives with a single letter representation. So I wonder what do I write instead? I'm getting error 500 all the time now. And I can't figure out how the path should be.

The guide I've been following is found [here](http://www.jroller.com/hasant/entry/fileupload_with_gwt)

**EDIT**
It was not some problem duo to the path. Still need help though with fixing this problem. I basically followed the steps in the url I posted on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unix paths start at a common root , denoted `/` and separates directories with a `/`
e.g. `/home/starcom` might be your home directory. So create a new directory, mkdir `/home/starcom/uploaded` and use that as the path. Or for testing you could perhaps just use `/tmp`

You can get more info [here](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html)

Comment: Seems it is was not related to some path problem. I have tried both `/tmp` and my `/home` directory now. Both returned error 500.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a 500 return code, that means the server encountered an error. This means that you should see an error message from the server somewhere. If you're running from Eclipse, you'll see the error on the Console tab. If you're running Tomcat, look for those logs.

You want to find the error message, since it'll probably explain what went wrong.